# Undefined date_diff()

Tags: php, datediff

I'm trying to use `date_diff()`:

```
$datetime1 = date_create('19.03.2010');
$datetime2 = date_create('22.04.2010');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%d days');
```

Its doesn't work for me, gives an error:

```
Call to undefined function  date_diff()
```

**How can I get it work?**

PHP 5.2 is used.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The function date_diff requires a PHP version of 5.3 or greater.

**UPDATE**

An example for PHP 5.2 (taken from the date_diff user comments).

```
<?php 
function date_diff($date1, $date2) { 
    $current = $date1; 
    $datetime2 = date_create($date2); 
    $count = 0; 
    while(date_create($current) < $datetime2){ 
        $current = gmdate("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($current))); 
        $count++; 
    } 
    return $count; 
} 

echo (date_diff('2010-3-9', '2011-4-10')." days <br \>"); 
?>
```

Comment: Any way to use it on PHP 5.2?

Comment: this solution is very inefficient

Comment: You asked how to get date_diff working, I answered with the clear answer of you can't and offered a simple solution, which came directly from the user comments for date_diff, I simply copy pasted it. There are numerous ways to tackle the issue. Subtract the two strtotime values and dividing it by the right segments would be another way. If you want a 'simple' way, upgrade PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version that doesn't use Date objects, but these are of no use anyways in 5.2.

```
function date_diff($d1, $d2){
    $d1 = (is_string($d1) ? strtotime($d1) : $d1);
    $d2 = (is_string($d2) ? strtotime($d2) : $d2);  
    $diff_secs = abs($d1 - $d2);
    return floor($diff_secs / (3600 * 24));
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using this approach since it doesn't consider possible daylight saving time changes:

<!-- language: lang-php -->
ini_set('date.timezone', 'America/Los_Angeles');
echo _date_diff('2011-03-13', '2011-03-14');
>> 0

Answer (score 1):

```
function date_diff($date1, $date2) { 
$count = 0; 
//Ex 2012-10-01 and 2012-10-20
if(strtotime($date1) < strtotime($date2))
{                       
  $current = $date1;                
  while(strtotime($current) < strtotime($date2)){ 
      $current = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($current))); 
      $count++; 
  } 
}                 
//Ex 2012-10-20 and 2012-10-01
else if(strtotime($date2) < strtotime($date1))
{           
  $current = $date2;                
  while(strtotime($current) < strtotime($date1)){ 
      $current = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($current))); 
      $count++;  
  }
  $current = $current * -1;
}
return $count; }
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Answer (score 1):

First convert both dates to mm/dd/yyyy format then do this :

```
 $DateDiff = floor( strtotime($datetime2 ) - strtotime( $datetime1 ) ) / 86400 ;

//this will yield the resultant difference in days
```

Comment: Great solution sqlchild

Comment: @JonMatthews : Thanks a lot Sir,my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

Converting your DateTime to Unix date type, and subtracting one from another:
The format->("U") is where the DateTime is converted.

```
$datetime1 = date_create('19.03.2010');
$datetime2 = date_create('22.04.2010');
$intervalInDays = ($datetime2->format("U") - $datetime1->format("U"))/(3600 * 24);
```

Not sure if this is Y2K38 safe but it's one of the simplest date_diff workarounds.